# C# OOP - Abstractify boilerplate / black box for reuse

Tags: c#, oop

```
public void ThisStructureIsRepeatedALot(){
        Bla bla = ProcessBla();
        if (bla != null) {

             // this part actually differs 

        }
    }

public void Addition(){
        Bla bla = ProcessBla();
        if (bla != null) {

            bla+=foo;
 // ... more complicated stuff  
        }
    }

public void Division(){
        Bla bla = ProcessBla();
        if (bla != null) {

            bla/=foo;
            // ... more complicated stuff differs from above 
        }
    }

// etc
```

Question exemplified by toy example structure above snippet

For a bunch of different methods that have similar boilerplate conditional before invoking their different code, what's the right way to abstractify it, so that not every one of these similar methods need to waste 2 lines (not counting bracket) on boiler plate?

Comment: Great question. Shame I have no idea what you are asking for :D

Comment: Another way is to pass continuation to ProcessBla itself: `ProcessBla(bla => { // complicated stuff here });`.

Comment: It's not clear why would every method call `ProcessBla()` (perhaps wrong design here), but I'd add `void` overload with delegate (e.g. `Action<Bla>`) which run it in case result of processing is not null, passing complicated stuff as lambda is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use C# 7 `TryParse` pattern.

```
bool TryProcessBla(out Bla bla)
{
   bla = ProcessBla();
   return bla != null;
}
```

And then

```
public void Addition()
{
    if (TryProcessBla(out Bla bla) {

        bla+=foo;
        // ... more complicated stuff  
    }
}
```

Notice that the pattern itself is not C# 7 specific, but the `out Bla bla` part that allows you to write this in a oneliner only exists in C# 7.